# Scanning files to index

Tags: android-studio

[Scanning files to index- Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkwbY.png)

I try to uninstall- install again Android Studio and Reinstall Windows, But that error still not resolved. How can I return to the old version? Hope to have everyone's help. Thank you <3